# apt-get upgrade samba for samba-tools_3.6.18-1ubuntu2_i386.deb

Tags: samba

I am trying to update my `samba` tool to a 3.6.18 which is the latest in the repository (http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/samba/) but apt-get says that my current samba which is 3.6.3 is the latest.

What am I missing?

```
# /etc/apt/sources.list
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20130820.1)]/ precise main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=samba), samba 3.6.3-2ubuntu2.6 *is* the latest for the `precise` release. The .deb archives you found in the pool belong to other releases (3.6.18-1ubuntu2 is available for `saucy`).

Since samba isn't in `precise-backports`, your best choice is probably to build the new package yourself, e.g. using `apt-get source` and `dpkg-buildpackage`. Manually installing the package built for `saucy` *may* work, but most likely it'll refuse to start or even install due to Precise also having much older versions of various libraries.

Comment: So if I have a printer but that prevents my printer to print with samba what is my options here is the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/967410